# Power map and the induced homomorphism

Tags: algebraic-topology

Let $h:S^1 \to S^1$ be the power map $h(z)=z^n$. Identify the induced homomorphism $h_*:\pi_1S^1\to \pi_1S^1$.

I'm having a hard time putting my thoughts on paper. I know that the power map is a rotation, so any loop $f$ in $S^1$ would be mapped to $f*f*\cdots*f$. Since $\pi_1S^1$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}$, $h_*$ is a multiplication by $n$. But how can I make the argument?

Comment: I don't think of power maps as rotations.

Comment: The way you make that argument is by applying the definition of $h_*$ in tandem with your chosen isomorphism $\pi_1(S^1) \to \mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: @Randall So I have $h_*([1])=[h\circ1]=[h]$. But how do I show that $[h]=n$?

Comment: I think making the argument precise depends on explicitly spelling out the isomorphism $\pi_1 S^1 \cong \mathbb{Z}$. If it is given by the Winding Number or Mapping Degree for example then you can do a direct computation for $h$.

Comment: Alternatively, I think you can just directly argue that $h$ is *equal to* the concatenation of $n$ copies of the identity loop.

Comment: @William This is not true for any standard definition of concatenation. If you concatenate on the right, the first half will be the (n-1)-fold concatenation and the second half will be the identity, whereas the exponential performs each loop in an equal portion of time.

Comment: Thank you Connor you are absolutely right, it's not equal on the nose, my mistake. I guess you would have to establish it inductively with reparametrization homotopies.